# Center an image when resizing

Tags: python, tkinter

Working with Tkinter, I need to center entities. When trying to center labels, it will only center it within the first row, and not the window.

I want it centered within the entire window. i.e. the middle. So far, it is only the middle of the top. is this possible?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

# New window, but text appears in the center of the center (the absolute center).
def whatsup():
    popup = Tk()
    popup.title("Cadillac")
    frame = Frame(popup)
    frame.pack()

    label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Wanna ride in my Cadillac?")
    label.pack()

root.title("I Love You")

# 1, 1
button = Button(root, text="Ayo girl", command=whatsup)
button.pack(side=LEFT)

# 1, 2, but to be 2, 2 soon after addition of new items.
canvas = Canvas(root, height=250, width=200)
imageOfCatherine=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('ccr_on_moon.jpg'))
canvas.create_image(-160, -100, anchor=NW, image=imageOfCatherine)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using `canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid` instead of `pack`, with `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` methods like this :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("I Love You")

# New window, but text appears in the center of the center (the absolute center).
def whatsup():
    popup = Tk()
    popup.title("Cadillac")
    frame = Frame(popup)
    frame.pack()

    label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Wanna ride in my Cadillac?")
    label.pack()

# 1, 1
button = Button(root, text="Ayo girl", command=whatsup)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

# 1, 2, but to be 2, 2 soon after addition of new items.
canvas = Canvas(root, height=250, width=200)
imageOfCatherine=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('ccr_on_moon.jpg'))
canvas.create_image(-160, -100, anchor=NW, image=imageOfCatherine)
canvas.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.rowconfigure([0,1,2], weight=1)
root.columnconfigure([0,1,2], weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

**Answer to comment**

This also works, but it's not centered the same way :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("I Love You")

# New window, but text appears in the center of the center (the absolute center).
def whatsup():
    popup = Tk()
    popup.title("Cadillac")
    frame = Frame(popup)
    frame.pack()

    label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Wanna ride in my Cadillac?")
    label.pack()

# 1, 1
button = Button(root, text="Ayo girl", command=whatsup)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

# 1, 2, but to be 2, 2 soon after addition of new items.
canvas = Canvas(root, height=250, width=200)
imageOfCatherine=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('ccr_on_moon.jpg'))
canvas.create_image(-160, -100, anchor=NW, image=imageOfCatherine)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='')

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure([0,1], weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you utalize 3 rows and 3 columns? Just configure first row and first column and do ```canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='')```. ^^

Comment: Are you sure about this ? I think you need to have 3 rows in order to set `weights`, so it stays centered even when resizing.

Comment: Nope, you don't. What basically happens is that the first row/column takes up all the available space and by setting ```sticky=''``` you tell the Grid-manager to not put the widget in any corner nor to stretch it in any way. So all it is left to do is to put it into the center. Feel free to try it out for me it works perfectly.

Comment: @Nummer_42O : see in my answer the code I tried with one row and `sticky=''`, but it didn't work and the image stayed top-left. Maybe I have a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: Yeah you completely removed ```rowconfigure``` and ```columnconfigure```. What I wanted you to do is to use them only on row/colum 0 not on all 3. ^^

Comment: Okay I see. You're right, it got centered, but no exactly the same way. My method works better to take the left button into account (in my opinion)

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean but when the window gets smaller your version does not work that good anymore too. Tbh is the solution from acw1668 still the best one because it just bypasses the grid manager totally

Comment: I usually avoid using `.place()`, but yeah in this case it just works perfectly.

Comment: Hi phoenix, this didn't work: The text in the popup is still centered, but only at the top.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering (no pun intended), I added `expand=YES` to `frame.pack()` in the `whatsup()` function.

```
def whatsup():
    popup = Tk()
    popup.title("Cadillac")
    frame = Frame(popup)
    frame.pack(expand=YES) # This was the changed line!

    label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Wanna ride in my Cadillac?")
    label.pack()
```

This allows for the popup text to become centered.